# PHP - Loop and not loop at the same time from a join

Tags: php, loops

I'm trying to display a company name from a company table, and then loop out news from another table. The two tables are joined. This means that: I want to just pick out one row from one table in the join, and loop out data from the other table in the join. Is this possible? My code below only display two out of three posts in the news table in my loop.

Thanks!

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            newID, newTitle, newSummary, newDate,
            comID, comName, comImageThumb
        FROM 
            tblNews a RIGHT JOIN tblCompanies b
        ON a.newCompanyID = b.comID
        ORDER BY newDate DESC";

// Get company name and display
$companyData = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$comName = $companyData['comName'];

echo "<a href='#' class='name'>$comName</a>";

// Looping news
while($news = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Display news posts
    $newTitle = $news['newTitle'];

    echo $newTitle;
}
```

Comment: off topic, but important: please note that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated and no longer being maintained. You are strongly recommended to switch to either the `mysqli` or `PDO` libs as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Put everything inside while loop and try :

```
while($news = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
// Get company name and display

$comName = $news ['comName'];

echo "<a href='#' class='name'>$comName</a>";

// Looping news

    // Display news posts
    $newTitle[] = $news['newTitle'];

    echo $newTitle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at mysql `GROUP_CONCAT` for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution probably would be to keep track of whether you are in the first iteration:

```
// query company name and news entries here

$firstRow = true;
while($news = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($firstRow) { echo $news['comName']; }
    $firstRow = false;

    echo $news['newTitle'];
}
```

You could also keep your current code and use `mysql_data_seek(0)` to reset the cursor after extracting the company name first.

And on a side note: Don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore! Use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, I still get only two out of three posts from the news table...

Comment: Are you sure that you have the `echo` for the news title inside of the `while`? I clarified that in the code above.

Comment: Yes :/ I skipped the join and separated the two tables but thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Move the fetch operation to the end of the loop:

```
$companyData = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$comName = $companyData['comName'];

echo "<a href='#' class='name'>$comName</a>";

    // you've already fetched a news item....

$news=$companyData;
do {
   $newTitle = $news['newTitle'];
   echo $newTitle;
} while ($news=mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```